# Corrupted file after `WordprocessingDocument.Open`

Tags: c#, openxml

I have problem with this:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true)) { }
```

Using just above and trying open document in Word showing error message that file is corrupted. It is interesting that for LibreOffice file is OK. I compared xml files (in docx) in WinMarge file before and after using this code and both are identical. Difference is only in size of docx file - why?

Comment: Did you create or modify the document LibreOffice prior to loading in Word? If so the former may not be compliant

Comment: Yes my original file is created in LibreOffice but MS Word can open it without any problems. The problem is when I open it with `WordprocessingDocument.Open` (using OpenXML), after this I can't open file in Word but can open in LibreOffice.

Comment: OK. How can the before and after documents be _"identical"_ but have a different file size?  Are you using a binary file comparer?

Comment: I unpacked XMLs from docx and compare - all files are identical. Maybe something with package (zip) is wrong? I done simple test.. I opened docx in LibreOffice, saved it again and then file is OK for MS Word.

Comment: Best way to compare to files is just to use any old _binary_ file comparer rather than trying to interpret application-level data.  A binary file comparer just compares files which is what is important here.

Comment: Binary compare says that files are different. Corrupted file is smaller. But files inside them are identical.

Comment: Logic suggests that they are not identical

Answer (score 2):

OK.. I resolved problem.. it's not nice solution but it's works..

```
var document = "template.docx";
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
{
    // some editing stuff
    wordDoc.Clone("ready.docx");
}
```

Now `template.docx` is corrupted, but `ready.docx` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, although your solution worked for me

> wordDoc.Clone("ready.docx");

I found that in my case it was problem with letter encoding. I had the file generated from abby, image text to docx generation. 
In order to check if encoding makes you trouble:

1. change youreditedword.**docx** to youreditedword.**zip**
2. open .zip, go to word folder, open document.xml
3. check document.xml' text that appears in word. If it is garbled, then you have encoding problem.

I fixed it this way - removed one phrase in my original unedited word file and writed it down again and saved it. Probably this way the encoding for the file is changed. Then after using openxml library and opening the file did not produce file is corrupted error